# Facebook Like Button doesn't work on my domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Almost all links are dead. they work on clicking, and then decrement the like box count
Check meta tags
http://www.thefunnyplanet.com/pic/Annual_meeting_of_women_drivers

checked the debugger url linter tool from facebook. No issues with meta tags
But the like button doesnt work, even if i put the url in the like box documentation page and test, it doesnt work

Can any1 help me?

Comment: The two like buttons on that link work fine...

Comment: strange, it works on some pages on the same domain, doesnt work at times... going crazy...

Answer (score 0):

I checked your link you provided above and noticed that you have 2 facebook likes. Once is rendered using iframe html and the other is using fb:like.  Both seem to be working fine for me, even holding the count correct when refreshing the page.

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2Fthefunnyplanet&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:21px;margin-bottom:-3px" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

<fb:like href="http://thefunnyplanet.com/pic/Annual_meeting_of_women_drivers" send="false" layout="button_count" width="20" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

This is confusing to me.  The iframe one is pointing to a Facebook page url while the later is pointing to the current website page.  Maybe this structure is confusing Facebook's javascript as well.  Can you try removing one or the other and seeing if it continues to give you problems.